# Throw error message if code is not working in catch block asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

I want to throw error related to the function in my code below if `try` block fails.

here is  my code

```
try
{
    FiberEngineer ObjFiber = new FiberEngineer();
    string strFiber = ObjFiber.UpdateFiberEngRecord(FiberDataInsertion, myJsonXML);

    if (strFiber.Split('|')[0] == "SUCCESS")
    {
        SendEmail(FiberDataInsertion.MODIFIED_BY, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME, FiberDataInsertion.REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE, FiberDataInsertion.PROG_ID); 
    }

    return Json(strFiber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //error message related to this string "strFiber"
}
```

How should I do this in asp.net

**update**

```
public JsonResult SaveRecordForFiberEng(FiberDataInsertion FiberDataInsertion, string myJsonXML)
    {
        string strFiber = "";
        try
        {
            FiberEngineer ObjFiber = new FiberEngineer();
            strFiber = ObjFiber.UpdateFiberEngRecord(FiberDataInsertion, myJsonXML);

            if (strFiber.Split('|')[0] == "SUCCESS")
            {
                SendEmail(FiberDataInsertion.MODIFIED_BY, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME, FiberDataInsertion.REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE, FiberDataInsertion.PROG_ID); 
            }

            return Json(strFiber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Exception(strFiber.Split('|')[0] + " ERROR| Error ocurred on Approve, Reject & Save Data");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills: is it proper `catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(strFiber.Split('|')[0]);
            }`

Comment: @mjwills: can u post as an answer as how should I check

Comment: @mjwills: then what should I do ?

Comment: @mjwills: its very rude bro, any ways I will take care of it. Your answer solves my issues :) a very much thanks

Comment: if I remove `throw` i get the above mentioned error. may be due to `jsonstring` class I guess. any idea how to deal with this. I upvoted too :)

Comment: @mjwills: my senior doesn't likes that `throw` part. and he wants me to remove that..

Comment: **Why** does he want it removed? Removing _just_ the `throw` **doesn't make sense.** Does he want the whole line removed? Did he suggest what to replace it with? Without that information we are playing a game of 'guess what I am thinking'.

Comment: ok. no issue will check again with him. IF there is any specific reason i will let u know

Comment: I know you think I am being rude, but when programming it is super helpful to explain **what you are trying to achieve**. _It is very hard for us to give you what you want if you aren't **clear** on what you want._

Comment: @mjwills : it’s weekend here mate, will clarify and let u know by Monday. Happy weekend. By the way I m much interested in Ashes now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to consider:

```
string strFiber = null;
try
{
    FiberEngineer ObjFiber = new FiberEngineer();
    strFiber = ObjFiber.UpdateFiberEngRecord(FiberDataInsertion, myJsonXML);

    if (strFiber.Split('|')[0] == "SUCCESS")
    {
        SendEmail(FiberDataInsertion.MODIFIED_BY, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME, FiberDataInsertion.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME, FiberDataInsertion.REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE, FiberDataInsertion.PROG_ID);
    }

    return Json(strFiber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var fiber = strFiber == null ? null : strFiber.Split('|').FirstOrDefault();
    throw new Exception($"fiber value was {fiber}");
}
```

The key is declaring `strFiber` **outside** of the `try..catch`. And also being cautious with `strFiber` inside the `catch` block (in case it is still `null`).

Comment: can i write without using `throw` ?

Comment: Your question **explicitly** states that you _want_ to throw. _But no, you don't **need** to throw. Change my `throw` line to whatever you want._

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:
Put this in catch block:

```
throw new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  // returns 400
```

If you want to include body text, then use a ViewResult, set the `Response.StatusCode` and the view containing the body.
Also you can log the exception in log file and you can see it.
Code will somethig like that in catch block:

```
logger.Error(ex.Message);
```